# How to add project file to non empty bitbucket repository(same project) fist time

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to connect local system with bit-bucket but getting the following error.
**fatal: remote origin already exists.** 
My local system have same project(some changes )as bit-bucket. But not connected to bit-bucket. This project has been already initialize with git. We are getting the remote origin already exists because previously I have pushed it into git bucket. I have download this project from git hub. Now I want to push it into bitbucket. **I don't want to remove my bit bucket project, but push my local project**

```
vagrant@localhost horizon]$ git remote add origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/horizon.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

I am searching the method where we don't pass the user's name with url but after press enter, It will ask username and password.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a remote called `origin` because you cloned from github. If you wan't to push only once, you can just add another remote:

```
$ git remote add bb https://user@bitbucket.org/user/horizon.git
$ git push bb master
```

If you want to change your origin, you edit origin:

```
$ git remote set-url origin https://user@bitbucket.org/user/horizon.git
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am searching the method where we don't pass the user's name with url but after press enter, It will ask username and password..